# Java log in plain text

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I redirected Java Logger to log in file using following code:

```
Handler handler = new FileHandler("test.log", LOG_SIZE, LOG_ROTATION_COUNT);
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);
```

but it logs in XML format. I want to be exactly like output (i.e. plain text). How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set a [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) on your Handler. Either create your own or use the [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html)

Comment: handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());