# How to log plain text in Java? SimpleFormatter also writes XML

Tags: java, logging

I am writing logfiles using SimpleFormatter. These are written in XML instead of plain text. The answers I found for writing it as plain text all only say to use the simple formatter (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469185/651779). This is my custom record formatter, which extends from SimpleFormatter:

```
class CustomRecordFormatter extends SimpleFormatter {
    @Override
    public String format(final LogRecord r) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(formatMessage(r)).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        if (null != r.getThrown()) {
            sb.append("Throwable occurred: "); //$NON-NLS-1$
            Throwable t = r.getThrown();
            PrintWriter pw = null;
            try {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                t.printStackTrace(pw);
                sb.append(sw.toString());
            } finally {
                if (pw != null) {
                    try {
                        pw.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // ignore
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

and this is how I set up the logger

```
public class DeconvolutionLogger {
  static private FileHandler outfilePath;
  protected final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
  static public void setup(String outputDir) throws IOException {
    // get the global logger to configure it
    log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    Date date = new Date();
    setOutfilePath(new FileHandler(outputDir+"/DeconvolutionLog_"+dateFormat.format(date)+".txt"));
    CustomRecordFormatter customFormatter = new CustomRecordFormatter();
    ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(customFormatter);
    log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
    log.addHandler(consoleHandler);
    log.addHandler(outfilePath);

  }
}
```

What am I missing that it does not write to plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatter of `outfilePath` is stil `XMLFormatter`.
You should call `outfilePath.setFormatter(customFormatter);` to change it.